# import multiple polymer web components in same file (getting error : .... a type with that name is already registered)

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

I just started using polymer for creating web-components.

When I import only one custom element everything is fine.

Now I want to use the polymer element iron-collapse in my custom web component and I want to import both of them in my HTML.

```
<link rel="import" href="../custom-accordion.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-collapse/iron-collapse.html">
```

Both of the elements are positioned inside a dom-module Tag in their files:

```
<dom-module id="custom-accordion">
  ....content
</dom-module>
```

and

```
<dom-module id="iron-collapse">
   ....content
</dom-module>
```

When I want to import both I get the error :

```
Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'dom-module'. A type with that name is already registered.)
```

I think I have to use this dom-module tag in both, otherwise I can't create my web-component. Right?

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dom-module is Polymer. The issue is polymer is running twice and trying to register dom-module element. In your code you are just using the dom-module element.

I am not sure how you are running your solution. Try below and see if it works

1. If you have included polymer in index.html, try removing it.
2. Try using polymer-starter-kit as your start. It takes care of most of these issues and comes packed with all the tools required to build a production ready polymer application. You can just focus on your code.

Comment: im running it like this (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/reusableelements.html https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/reusableelements.html). i just changed the seed-element to my needs. and installed iron-collapse and try to import it in my index.html

Comment: Ok it works with the starter kit. Thanks. But I still don't understand why I had (have) this issue.

Comment: If you are importing polymer.html from two different file into your index.html file then I might cause issue. You can move all your imports to elements.html file and then import elements.html file into your index.html file. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Polymer-element in a script-tag inside your dom-module? You need to rename this as well :

```
<dom-module id="**yourElementName**">
    <template>
       [...]
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "**yourElementName**",
           [...]
        })
    </script>
</dom-module>
```